# Are the Latin word “focus” and the Old Slavonic пещь (peshch') "stove" cognates?

Tags: etymology

Can anybody please explain to me why the Latin word focus "fireplace" and the Old Slavonic word пещь (peshch') "stove"* are not cognates (PIE /f/ yields Old Slavonic /p/)?

The Old Slavonic letter щ (shch) is always derived from the letters к (k) or г (g) + т (t); Я пеку (Ya peku) "I bake"

*see "The russian stove"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Latin and does not show any particular research effort.

Answer (score 5):

Grimm's Law only applies to Germanic languages; PIE as usually reconstructed has no `*f`.

Latin *focus* probably comes from PIE `*bʰ-h₂-` "shine" (see *fax* "torch"); Slavic пещь seems to come from PIE `*p-kʷ-` "cook". They're not related.